# While click on add Button the list view is adding same data again

Tags: android, android-listview

In my app when the listview has an item1 in it again on adding new data item1 and item 2 are showing but past item1 data is also there means(item1,item1,item2) this is what I'm getting.
In this, the list view is getting data properly but when I add new data it should update the listview rather than adding all the data below the old data

E.g:

I have added A in list view its shows A, now I added B in List view than it should show A,B but it's showing A,A,B

```
    public class Payment extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    Spinner spinner;
    TextView tvPayDate;
    LinearLayout llAccountNo, llChequeNo, llbankName, llDate, llAmount, llAdd;
    Button btnAdd, btnSubmit;
    Calendar calendar;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
    private String date;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    EditText edtAccountNo, edtChequeNo, edtBankName, edtDate, edtAmount, edtOtherText;
    String strAccountNo="", strDate="", strAmount="",  strMonth="", strYear="", strBranch="", strCheckNo="", paymentMode="";
    String token, aksk_no;
    ListView userList;
    UserCustomAdapter userAdapter;
    ArrayList<PayModel> userArray = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);

        tvPayDate = findViewById(R.id.tvPayDate);

        edtAccountNo = findViewById(R.id.edtAccountNo);
        edtChequeNo = findViewById(R.id.edtChequeNo);
        edtBankName = findViewById(R.id.edtBankName);
        edtDate = findViewById(R.id.edtDate);
        edtAmount = findViewById(R.id.edtAmount);
        edtOtherText = findViewById(R.id.edtOtherText);
        llAccountNo = findViewById(R.id.llAccountNo);
        llChequeNo = findViewById(R.id.llChequeNo);
        llbankName = findViewById(R.id.llbankName);
        llDate = findViewById(R.id.llDate);
        llAmount = findViewById(R.id.llAmount);
        llAdd = findViewById(R.id.llAdd);
        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c);
        String[] separated = formattedDate.split("/");
        strMonth = separated[0];
        strYear = separated[1];
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("ManaShakti", MODE_PRIVATE);
        token = prefs.getString("token", "");
        aksk_no = prefs.getString("aksk_no", "");
        Intent in = getIntent();
        // tvtotalhrs.setText(in.getStringExtra("hrs"));
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.transaction_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        date = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        tvPayDate.setText(date);
        userAdapter = new UserCustomAdapter(Payment.this, R.layout.row,
                userArray);
        userList =  findViewById(R.id.listView);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (paymentMode.equals("Cash")) {
                    strDate = edtDate.getText().toString();
                    strAmount = edtAmount.getText().toString();
                    int number = Integer.parseInt(edtAmount.getText().toString());
                    if (number > 2000) {
                        edtAmount.setError("Amount should be less than 2000");
                    } else {
                        Add();
                    }
                }
                else if (paymentMode.equals("Cheque")) {
                        strDate = edtDate.getText().toString();
                        strAmount = edtAmount.getText().toString();
                        strCheckNo = edtAccountNo.getText().toString();
                        strBranch = edtBankName.getText().toString();
                    Add();
                }
                else if (paymentMode.equals("UPI Transaction")) {
                        strDate = edtDate.getText().toString();
                        strAmount = edtAmount.getText().toString();
                        strBranch = edtBankName.getText().toString();
                    Add();
                }
                else if (paymentMode.equals("Demand Draft")) {
                        strDate = edtDate.getText().toString();
                        strAmount = edtAmount.getText().toString();
                        strCheckNo = edtAccountNo.getText().toString();
                        strBranch = edtBankName.getText().toString();
                    Add();
                }
            }
        });

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                submitData();
           //     checkInputFields();
            }
        });
    }
    private void Add() {
        String akskno = aksk_no.trim();
        final String token1 = token.trim();
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("a_k_s_no", akskno.trim());
        params.put("year", strYear);
        params.put("month", strMonth);
        params.put("transaction_type", paymentMode);
        params.put("amount", strAmount);
        params.put("bank_name", strBranch);
        params.put("check_dd_no", strAccountNo);
        params.put("date", tvPayDate.getText().toString());
        params.put("token", token1.trim());
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(params);
        String url = "";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url
                , json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                    String status = object.getString("status");
                    if (status.equals("200")) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray dataJsonArray = object.optJSONArray("data");
                            for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                PayModel playerModel = new PayModel();
                                JSONObject dataa = dataJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                playerModel.setPaymentMode(dataa.getString("transaction_type"));
                                playerModel.setAmount( dataa.getString("amount"));
                                playerModel.setDate( dataa.getString("date"));
                                playerModel.setId( dataa.getString("transaction_id"));
                                playerModel.setAksk_no( dataa.getString("a_k_s_no"));
                                playerModel.setToken(token1);
                                userArray.add(playerModel);
                            }
                            setupListview();

                        } catch (JSONException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else if (status.equals("201")) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray dataJsonArray = object.optJSONArray("data");
                            for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                PayModel playerModel = new PayModel();
                                JSONObject dataa = dataJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                playerModel.setPaymentMode(dataa.getString("transaction_type"));
                                playerModel.setAmount( dataa.getString("amount"));
                                playerModel.setDate( dataa.getString("date"));
                                playerModel.setId( dataa.getString("transaction_id"));
                                playerModel.setAksk_no( dataa.getString("a_k_s_no"));
                                playerModel.setToken(token1);
                                userArray.add(playerModel);
                            }
                            setupListview();
                        } catch (JSONException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(Payment.this, "Some Details are Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Akash", " " + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Payment.this, "" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
    private void setupListview() {
        userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
    }
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Cash")) {
            paymentMode = "Cash";
            llAccountNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llChequeNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llbankName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llAmount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Cheque")) {
            paymentMode = "Cheque";
            llAccountNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llChequeNo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llbankName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llAmount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("UPI Transaction")) {
            paymentMode = "UPI Transaction";
            llAccountNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llChequeNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llbankName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llAmount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Demand Draft")) {
            paymentMode = "Demand Draft";
            llAccountNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llChequeNo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llbankName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llAmount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void checkInputFields() {
        if (edtAccountNo.getText() != null)
            strAccountNo = edtAccountNo.getText().toString();
        if (edtChequeNo.getText() != null)
            strCheckNo = edtChequeNo.getText().toString();
        if (edtBankName.getText() != null)
            strBranch = edtBankName.getText().toString();
        if (edtDate.getText() != null)
            strDate = edtDate.getText().toString();
        if (edtAmount.getText() != null)
            strAmount = edtAmount.getText().toString();
        if (!strDate.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !strAmount.equalsIgnoreCase("")
        ) {
            submitData();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All fields are mandatory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    private void submitData() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Payment.this, Upload.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And here is My Adapter

```
    public class UserCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PayModel> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    ArrayList<PayModel> data = new ArrayList<PayModel>();


    public UserCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                             ArrayList<PayModel> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        UserHolder holder = null;
        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new UserHolder();
            holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.textAddress = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.textLocation = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            holder.textId = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            holder.btnDelete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        PayModel user = data.get(position);
        holder.textName.setText(user.getPaymentMode());
        holder.textAddress.setText(user.getAmount());
        holder.textLocation.setText(user.getDate());
        holder.textId.setText(user.getId());
        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            String date1 = data.get(position).getDate();
            String[] items1 = date1.split("-");
            String date2 = items1[0];
            String month = items1[1];
            String year = items1[2];
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("a_k_s_no", data.get(position).getAksk_no());
                params.put("year", year);
                params.put("month",month);
                params.put("transaction_id", data.get(position).getId());
                params.put("token", data.get(position).getToken());
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(params);
                String url = "";
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url
                        , json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                            String status = object.getString("status");
                            if (status.equals("200")) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent=new Intent(context,Payment.class);
                                context.startActivity(intent);
                                ((Activity)context).finish();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e("Akash", " " + e);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                mQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            }
        });
        return row;
    }
    static class UserHolder {
        TextView textName;
        TextView textAddress;
        TextView textLocation;
        TextView textId;
        Button btnDelete;
    }
}
```

Comment: use list.clear() to clear the list before adding the new data.

Answer (score 0):

You need clear Arraylist before add data from server.
You need to clear data in this method ,

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        userArray.clear()// add it first line 
    }
```

Comment: can you just tell me in adapter when i am deleting one item how should i set new list view in adapter

Comment: After success of delete,you need  to call two method data.remove(position) and UserCustomerAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: One things You should do , userArray.clear() call it inside   if (status.equals("200")) { } and else if (status.equals("201")). and. remove from top you declared before. and Add it first line both case. because if not receive 
 data from server(server error case) your list view not showing any data.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answer, when you get completely new whole list you should, at first, clear previous list via `userArray.clear()` and then call `userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. 
If you got data that should be additional to already existing in `userArray`, you should call `add()`.

Comment: `                        JSONArray dataJsonArray = object.optJSONArray("data");
                        userArray.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            ...
                        }
                        userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`